# Pasar ficheros por línea de comandos en Visual Studio 2015

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2015, cmd

tengo un programa que para su ejecución necesita que se le pasen 2 ficheros por línea de comandos de la siguiente forma `./programa fich1 fich2`.
El problema que tengo es el siguiente , llevo mi corto aprendizaje de programador en Linux y por lo que sé la extensiones en Windows son `.exe`para la ejecución por lo que no sé si la configuración de la línea de comandos será igual.
De todos modos la idea es bastante simple, es simplemente pasarle por línea de comandos al Visual Studio lo quiero ejecutar, pero no sé como se si se ejecuta como  en Linux poniendo `/programa fich1 fich2` o de alguna otra forma porque es un `.exe`.

Muchas gracias.
Pd:Tenía una duda del mismo estilo en el QtCreator pero era en Linux y de ahí mi confusión ahora.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debes usar [start](http://es.wikihow.com/ejecutar-un-programa-desde-el-S%C3%ADmbolo-del-sistema) para ejecutar un programa desde la linea de comandos por ejemplo

```
start fich.exe
```

Comment: Pero y si quiero pasarle por el main 2 ficheros como mencione antes que tendría que hacer?                                   `start fich.exe fich1 fich2`

Comment: debería funcionar, también puedes crearte un fichero .bat que al ejecutarlo se ejecuten estos 2 .exe que quieres mira [aquí](http://www.downloadsource.es/como-crear-archivo-bat-para-ejecutar-comandos-en-cmd-automaticamente-windows/n/8520/)